# How do I fix the failure: SQL Server 2012 Setup

Tags: sql-server, installation

I'm trying to installed SQL Server Express 2012. But at the end of the setup process I get two failures.

1) Database Engine Services

2) SQL Server Replication.

It says to uninstalled these features but I can not find them. Does anybody know what components I might be missing?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Somebody please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38916894/6709147

Answer (score 0):

When setup fails first place to look for is setup log file, which get created at `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\`. This [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx) should give you more idea about the log file.

It is very possible that this log file has more details about the error and possible causes for the failure.