# I am getting Status as "Not Started" in installing setup files step while installing SQL Server 2012 Advanced edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

The Progress bar is looping infinitely without any progress

![Error Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWfLp.png

Comment: As there is no error message seen it is difficult to answer the question.
Kindly go through the following steps `
1. To install SQL Server, follow these steps:
2. Review installation requirements, system configuration checks, and security considerations for a SQL Server installation.
3. Run SQL Server Setup to install or upgrade to a later version.
4. Use SQL Server utilities to configure SQL Server.`
[Got To link for more information ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx)